# multiple keys for one value in yaml

Tags: arrays, yaml, key

Is it possible to use different keys for the same value?

```
[activerecord, activemodel]: 'test'
```

I expect the same result as with this:

```
activerecord: 'test'
activemodel: 'test'
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That doesn't work because YAML allows you to specify keys of any type, so

```
[activerecord, activemodel]: 'test'
```

is a mapping with a single key, the sequence `[activerecord, activemodel]` whose value is `'test'`.

Instead, you can use an anchor/alias:

```
activerecord: &my_value 'test'
activemodel: *my_value
```

However, there's no way of attaching both keys to the single value in one key/value pair.