# Rails - How to avoid repeating same i18n attributes translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, dry

I am building a Rails application using I18n translations.

I have two models (Blog and Event), sharing same attributes (title, content).
In my I18n yml files, how can I avoid repeating same keys for each attributes models and share them ?

Extract of my actual code:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      blog:
        title: Titre
        content: Contenu
      event:
        title: Titre
        content: Contenu
```

I also tried to set attributes as default, removing wrapped model key without any luck.

```
fr:
   activerecord:
      attributes:
        title: Titre
        content: Contenu
```

Thanks for your help !

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2.7.1
- Ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar kind of question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910818/4758119)

You can achieve it using yaml aliases

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      blog: &title_content
        title: Titre
        content: Contenu
      event: *title_content
```

Refer [yaml aliases](https://github.com/cyklo/Bukkit-OtherBlocks/wiki/Aliases-(advanced-YAML-usage)) for more info.

Comment: Thanks ! It helps me to have a better understanding of how yaml works !