# Different yaml keys with same value

Tags: yaml

Can we simplify this yaml key and value pair ?

[image]

FYI: i found this question,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255311/multiple-keys-for-one-value-in-yaml). But not sure how to arrange it with proper identation.

Answer (score 2):

According to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910818/12196329) you mentioned, you can do something like this.

```
 a:
     b:
         c: &my_value 700
         d: *my_value
         e: *my_value
         f: *my_value
```